# using spread syntax with ternary operator inside object literal

Tags: javascript

Consider following code, where one object is composed from two parts: values and their corresponding descriptions:

```js
let flagConfigObj = {};

const features = {
  f1: {
    value: 1,
    type: 'type1'
  },
  f2: {
    value: 2,
    type: 'type2'
  }
};

let featuresDescription = {
  f1: {
    description: 'desc 1'
  },
  f2: {
    description: 'desc 2'
  }
};

Object.keys(features).forEach(key => {
  flagConfigObj[key] = {
    ...features[key],
    ...(featuresDescription[key] || { some: 'backup' })
  };
});

console.log(flagConfigObj);
```

As you might notice, when composite is constructed, there is `||` operator preventing form spreading non-existing object and replacing it with some default templates. And so, output for this code will be:

```
{ 
  f1: { value: 1, type: 'type1', description: 'desc 1' },
  f2: { value: 2, type: 'type2', description: 'desc 2' } 
}
```

But when corresponding description field in `featuresDescription` is missing, it's replaced to:

```
{ 
  f1: { value: 1, type: 'type1', description: 'desc 1' },
  f2: { value: 2, type: 'type2', some: 'backup' } 
}
```

**The question**

How to replace `||` syntax with ternary operator `?:`?
I've tried some funny combinations like

```
featuresDescription[key] ? ...featuresDescription[key] : {some: 'backup'}
{featuresDescription[key]} ? ...featuresDescription[key] : {some: 'backup'}
```

But all of them gives syntax error, and I'm feeling now like just blindly randomizing positions of `[,],},{,...` instead of truly understanding it...

Any help as always is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spread syntax is part of the object initializer grammar but not part of the general expression grammar, so your entire `? :` has to be to the right:

```
 ... featuresDescription[key] ? featuresDescription[key] : { some: "backup" }
```

In this particular case, there's not any effective difference between this and the original with the simple `||`. The expression

```
expr1 ? expr1 : expr2
```

means, "if expr1 evaluates to a "truthy" value, use its value; otherwise use the value of expr2".  That is precisely the same as what

```
expr1 || expr2
```

means. (Well, ignoring possible side-effects of `expr1`, which would be an even stronger incentive to using the simpler `||` form unless you're laying booby-traps for some future programmer.)

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Do we have some fine documentation to explain concepts of `initializer grammar` and `general expression grammar`? So basically, to read your statement it would be like "ok all, I'm spreading, if `featuresDescription[key]` exist, it will be spreed, otherwise `{ some: "backup" }`"?

Comment: The spec of course has this all in excruciating detail. The key thing to remember is that spread syntax is **not** an "operator"; it's a syntax that shows up in certain situations, not just at arbitrary points in an expression.

Comment: And that's a point. That's wy I'm considering your answer to be more issue-centric tan other, more common approach with wrapping ternary with parenthesis before spread (i.e. `...(expr : v1 ? v2)` because this approach builds up a falsy feeling, that `...` is an operator and by surrounding it with parenthesis you are forcing somehow operators precedence.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would work

```js
...(featuresDescription[key] ? featuresDescription[key] : { some: 'backup' })
```

full example:

```js
let flagConfigObj = {};

const features = {
  f1: {
    value: 1,
    type: 'type1'
  },
  f2: {
    value: 2,
    type: 'type2'
  },
  f3: {
    value: 3,
    type: 'type3'
  }
};

let featuresDescription = {
  f1: {
    description: 'desc 1'
  },
  f2: {
    description: 'desc 2'
  },
};


Object.keys(features).forEach(key => {
  flagConfigObj[key] = {
    ...features[key],
    ...(featuresDescription[key] ? featuresDescription[key] : { some: 'backup' })
  };
});

console.log(flagConfigObj);
```

However, I still prefer using `||` as below

```js
...(featuresDescription[key] || { some: 'backup' })
```

because it is simpler and not repetitive regarding `featuresDescription[key]`

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes ,indeed `||` is cleaner, but replacing it with `:?` was rather an "mental gymnastics" to prove myself, that I'm not so right about usages of spread :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be the syntax you are looking for;

```js
Object.keys(features).forEach(key => {
        flagConfigObj[key] = {
            ...features[key],
            ...(featuresDescription[key] ? featuresDescription[key] : {some: 'backup'})
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the default expression in parenthese before spreading the object.

```js
let flagConfigObj = {};

const features = { f1: { value: 1, type: 'type1' }, f2: { value: 2, type: 'type2' } };
let featuresDescription = { f1: { description: 'desc 1' }, f2: { description: 'desc 2' } };

Object.keys(features).forEach(key => {
  flagConfigObj[key] = {
    ...features[key],
    ...(featuresDescription[key] || { some: 'backup' })
  }
})

console.log(flagConfigObj)
```

Comment: This makes sense, but whole idea is to get rid of `||` in favor of `?:`